# Access Postgres database remotely that's hosted on Azure in docker container with webapi

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure cloud services so excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I have a docker-compose file with a .Net core webapi and postgres database. I have it running on Azure as a web-app and its working (I can see when I query the API that there's data in the database). However I would like to get access to the database remotely so that I can inspect and see the data in the database via pgAdmin or something similar.

I did bind a port to my pgAdmin site in my docker-compose but it does not seem like that port is open. I've read somewhere that only port 80 and 443 can be exposed from Azure web-apps when using multi-image containers. (This docker-compose works locally 100% and I can access the pgAdmin site and see the database with all its tables).

So my question is, how do I run my web-api with my postgres database on azure and have visibility to my database?

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    container_name: 'bootcampapi'
    image: 'myimage'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - bootcampbackend-network

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    restart: always
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myusername
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=database-name
      - PGDATA=database-data
    networks:
      - bootcampbackend-network
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 15433:80
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - bootcampbackend-network
    volumes:
      - database-other:/var/lib/pgadmin/

networks:
  bootcampbackend-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, App Service only listens on one port. One solution around that is to use a reverse proxy like Nginx to route the traffic to both your containers.

BTW, build, depends_on and networks are unsupported. [See doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the docs, that is helpful. I'll look into Nginx.